# Compress bytes into a readable string (no null or endofline)

Tags: string, compression

I'm searching for the most appropriated encoding or method to compress bytes into character that can be read with a ReadLine-like command that only recognizes readable char and terminates on end of line char. There is probably a common practice to achieve it, but I don't know a lot about encoding.

Currently, I'm outputing bytes as a string of hex, so I need 2 bytes to represent 1 byte. It works well, but it is slow. Ex: byte with a value 255 is represented as 'FF'.

I'm sure it could be 3 or 4 times smaller, though there's a limit since I'm outputing MP3 data, but I don't know how. Should I just ZIP my string or there would be too much overhead on it?

Will ASCII85 contains random null bytes and EndOfLine or I'm safe with it?

Comment: Perhaps youd like to use [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't zip mp3 files, that will not gain much (or anything at all).

I'm a bit disappointed that you did not read up on [Ascii85](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii85) before asking as I think the Wikipedia article explains fairly clearly that it uses only printable ASCII characters; so, no line endings or null bytes. It is efficient and the conversion is also fairly simple and quick - split your data to 4-byte ints; you will convert these to just five Ascii85 digits by repeatedly dividing the int value by 85 and taking ASCII value of the modulo + 33.

You can also consider using Base64 or UUEncode. These are fairly popular (e.g. used in email attachments) so you will find many libraries preparing these. But they are less efficient.

Comment: Sorry, I should have read about Ascii85. I'm on the end, I hope, of an 8 days long coding problem, so I'm beginning to be less strategic. Yes, I'll definitely use Ascii85 as I found a snippet to put in my .Net.